# Retrieve count of related records

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I currently have two tables in my data source that I'm referencing in this instance. 
Firstly, to explain the context, I have a windows form program in VB.NET (Visual Studio 2013).

In the first table Trainer, I have the following fields : ID, First Name, Surname, Contact, Class.

In the second table Member, I have the following fields : ID, First Name, Surname, Contact, Type, TrainerID.

I have enforced referential integrity between the two tables using Trainer.ID as PK and Member.TrainerID as FK with a 1:m relationship. I'm trying to retrieve the count of related records, to the specified ID of the trainer. I want to retrieve the count of related records. So, for example on the form I click Search and provide a trainer ID, I'd like to return the amount of customers he/she has belonging to them.

I need that, so that I can work out their salary based on commission + base amount.
I've looked around a lot, read up a lot but I just can't seem to get it. Any help whatsoever will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an ORM like EF / L2S / NHibernate etc.? This sort of thing is *really* trivial if you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the trainer id, can't you just do:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from member m
where m.trainerid = @TheTrainerId;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(m.id) as count_members
from trainer t
left join member m on m.trainerid = t.id
where t.surname = 'watson'
```

Comment: @bukart: Please stop making unneeded code changes to other users posts. I like the formatting just the way I made it. And you even put an syntax error in it.

Comment: ouch... sry, my fault